# Masstransit Saga state machine not working with Send message from consumer with Azure Service Bus in .Net Core

Tags: masstransit

We are implementing **Saga state machine** pattern using **Masstransit**.
Typical structure is we have different microservices which are performing DB operations and Saga state machine is used to manage the distributed transactions.
We have implemented this with **Azure Service BUS**. We are using **Publish **method for event so that state machine can transition to next state and continue further. One observation is with publish it creates **many queues **which are coupled with event types.

Problem - We want to reduce the number of queues and looking for solution which can work with Topic - Subscription. We are using Send method to send the message to specific Topic-subscription.
We are able to add filters to make sure that we can consume message with specific consumer. Issue in this approach is after consumer consumed the message control is not returning back to state machine.
is there a way we can use Masstransit with Topic-Subscription based execution which use Send method and not Publish.
Code has structure as -
Solution -

```
 | -- SagaStateMachine.csproj
     -- SagaStateMachineConfiguration.cs 
 | -- Order.csproj
     -- OrderRequestedConsumer.cs
     -- OrderFailedConsumer.cs
     -- OrderInitiatedConsumer.cs
     -- OrderCompletedConsumer.cs  
| -- Stock.csproj
     -- StockRequestedConsumer.cs
     -- StockFailedConsumer.cs
     -- StockInitiatedConsumer.cs
     -- StockCompletedConsumer.cs  
| -- Billing.csproj
     -- BillingRequestedConsumer.cs
     -- BillingFailedConsumer.cs
     -- BillingCompletedConsumer.cs
```

After OrderRequestedConsumer is executed, I want to raise OrderInitiatedEvent which needs to perform 2 actions -

```
 1. Call OrderInitiatedConsumer.cs
 2. In state machine change the state and call StockRequestedEvent.cs which will be handled by StockRequestedConsumer.cs
```

When i use send method Statemachine is unable to execute 2 steps

**Added more context - 18 Jan**

When we implement with Queue based approach with those number of consumers it resulted into creating around 11 queues ..we are not sure how practical that would be to manage those many queues.  For project we might need different saga implementation for different domains which means more Queues. Also this deployment needs to be done on AKS ( Azrue Kubernetes Service) and as per standard which we want to follow is to make sure that we have required infra in place considering the Queues also.

current sample implementation which we have is like below -

```
  cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(nameof(OrderRequestedEvent), x =>
  {
      x.ConfigureConsumer<OrderRequestedConsumer>(context);
  });
  cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(nameof(OrderInitiatedEvent), x =>
  {
      x.ConfigureConsumer<OrderInitiatedConsumer>(context);
  });
  cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(nameof(OrderFailedEvent), x =>
  {
      x.ConfigureConsumer<OrderFailedConsumer>(context);
  });

  cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(nameof(OrderCompletedEvent), x =>
  {
      x.ConfigureConsumer<OrderCompletedConsumer>(context);
  });
```

like wise other consumers are also registered.

In saga state machine we have

```
During(OrderRequested,
     When(OrderRequestedEvent)
      .Then(context =>
      {
          Console.WriteLine($"Order Requested");      
      })
      .Publish(context =>
          new StockRequested
          {
              CorrelationId = context.Instance.CorrelationId,
              OrderId = context.Instance.OrderId
          })
     .TransitionTo(OrderRequested),
     When(OrderFailedEvent)
      .Then(context => .....
```

Is this correct implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Using subscriptions on topics in this way is not a great idea, subscriptions aren't queues and are more complex to manage. If you have related consumers, put them on the same queue.

MassTransit has plenty of [videos](https://youtu.be/8marp1oyY_I) on YouTube about how it manages the topology in Azure Service Bus.

That said, those consumers seem more like events to be managed by a saga. Better approach than using separate consumers.

Comment: Thanks @Chris Patterson for quick reply. 
I have added more context for Queue based implementation. can you please verify if that's what your suggestion is and I have query regarding managing the queues.
Can you also please explain what is expected when you say - That said, those consumers seem more like events to be managed by a saga. Better approach than using separate consumers.

Comment: Unfortunately, your update just made things worse. I'd suggest spending more time understanding MassTransit from the samples, videos, and documentation.

Comment: Thanks  @Chris Patterson. I have gone through different videos and i am going through sample for Azure Service Bus from Masstransit repo (https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-AzureServiceBus/tree/master).  Also going through documentation for Azure Service Bus - specifically for SubscriptionEndpoint (https://masstransit.io/documentation/transports/azure-service-bus#subscriptions).
Based on scenario which i am working on, is there any sample available which has multi stage saga state machine implemented which is spanning across different services.